# Array initialization error

Tags: java

I am doing java programming practice from a website. I have to display this out put using arrays.

```
Enter the number of students: 3
Enter the grade for student 1: 55
Enter the grade for student 2: 108
Invalid grade, try again...
Enter the grade for student 2: 56
Enter the grade for student 3: 57
The average is 56.0
```

This is my source code so far, it is raising error `The local variable grades may not have been initialized`. How do I recover this? I have to make this program using arrays.

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numStudents = 0;
        int[] grades;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of students : ");
        numStudents = Integer.parseInt(in.next());

          for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
              System.out.print("Enter grade of student "+i+" :");
              grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
int[] grades;
```

you declare a variable called `grades`, that can hold a value of type `int[]`. However, before you can use it you also have to **initialize it**, eg create the actual data structure. This is done  like this:

```
int[] grades = new int[numStudents];
```

Note that you need to know the size beforehand when you declare an `array`, so you will have to move the creation of the array to just before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

All variables declared in methods have to be assigned a value before you read them to avoid trash values.

Also in java arrays are objects, that means that you have to create an array instance with `new` and assign it to grades before you can store anything in it.

```
 grades = new int[numStudents];
```

Answer (score 0):

An array doesn't have a constant memory allocation, therefor you must allocate memory to the new array.

for example

```
int[] grades = new int [numStudents]
```

This of course should be written only after you know the value of numStudents

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to add to what Keppil already said, but I'd like to add a little 'why'.

You see, when int[] grades is created, it is nothing but an 'empty pointer', pointing to a random location in memory.

By assigning the return value of 'new int[numGrades]', the value of the pointer points to the location in memory, which has been assigned. This memory is in the exact size of 'size of an integer multiplied by the number of grades', and can be accessed safely.

If this array is dimensioned too small (or not at all), a memory violation exception usually gets triggered, because you're writing memory you have no access to, often causing your program to crash or other undefined behavior.

Please remember: Arrays are different from normal variables.

So yeah, to make it short:

grades = new int[numGrades]; is what you're looking for.
Straight below the line, where you're parsing the the input number of students.

As an additional advice: User input is ALWAYS a source for error.
Make sure to include error handling for invalid output. (For example if some wiseguy decides to input 'John Smith' instead of a grade.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise variable before its usage.

Please see one of correct version of your code:

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numStudents = 0;
        int[] grades;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of students : ");
        numStudents = in.nextInt();

        // this line was added
        grades = new int[numStudents];

        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
              System.out.print("Enter grade of student "+i+" :");
              grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        }

        // closing used resources is a good practice
        in.close();
    }

}
```